# Question worth closing, but I disagree with popular reason

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

In the Close Votes queue, I often see questions that are near close threshold (3-4 votes), but the most popular close reason is not something I agree with.

So, suppose question is worth closing, but if I do vote, as far as I understand my username will be displayed "as a signature" under the winning close reason, even if it's not the one I voted for.

---

One example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5088133

When I opened that review item, "Unclear what you're asking" has 3 votes, so no matter how I vote, this will be the winning reason. However, I think the question can be inferred, "I have a syntax error and cannot find it". The code is there, and even a good-faith attempt at providing expected functionality is there.

The newest close reason (Off-topic > "why isn't this code working?") is much better and provides guidance to the user to include the exact error. But I effectively cannot vote for it.

---

Should I still vote to close, even if I disagree with popular opinion on the reason?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main goal should be to close off-topic or otherwise unsuitable questions, so I'd *still vote to close*.

If you feel strongly about your dissenting opinion about why it should be closed, leave a comment on the post when closing.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, you should still vote to close if you believe the question should be closed.

Secondly, you may not be "miscredited" at all, depending on how much you disagree. Your name will always appear by the main close reason (unclear/off-topic/duplicate/etc.). However, it will only also appear by the most popular sub-reason if you also voted to close for that reason.

For example (from English Language Learners):

[image]

Notice that there are five users who voted to close but only three of them thought that "add more research" was the reason to close.