# Extend "specific close reason" signatures to all close reasons

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I while ago I asked this question on Meta: [Question worth closing, but disagree with popular reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260890/question-worth-closing-but-disagree-with-popular-reason)

[starsplusplus's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260892/934239) indicated that after a question is closed, only those who voted on the most popular close reason are listed under the exact close reason text:

[image: Close reason signatures]

Unfortunately, only off-topic reasons count as "specific reasons". Compare:

- [Question closed as off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5727596) - lists people voted for the winning reason
- [Question closed as too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5727357) - does not list people voted for the reason

In both cases, my close vote was different from the winning vote, but it's only visible in the first case.

Is it possible to extend this feature for all close reasons?

If anyone needs a concrete example where the consensus vote is extremely bad, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5772685). How is that *opinion-based*? I want this question closed as "Why isn't my code working..", but it was too late.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54917/165773

Comment: SO misrepresented me as having voted to close for a reason I considered incorrect once too often. It won't happen again, because I am not going to vote to close any question until it is fixed.

Comment: Why do people care so much about this? That's not a rhetorical question, I assume it actually is important, and want to know why. Personally, if the appropriate close reason isn't a slam-dunk to me, I usually add a comment explaining further in hopes it'll prompt the asker to respond or, better, just edit the question, so it may not affect me anyway, but I know most people just pick the best one and go with it even if it's iffy.

Comment: @abarnert There are two reasons to close questions. The first is _"kill it with fire"_ reason when all you want is to quickly banish an abomination of a question, and then it really doesn't matter. The second is to try and steer the user that asked the question towards improvement of this and/or future questions. It's possible to take an effort and explain everything in individual comments, but close reasons exist, excuse the pun, for a _reason_. They ought to be an efficient tool for that precise purpose, and the current system has a flaw.

Comment: *"but I know most people just pick the best one and go with it..."* - face it... often the best is not picked. Many reviewers are just lazy. Cf, [Swift how to truncate float to 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775134/swift-how-to-truncate-float-to-2-decimals). It get worse on some tags, like [tag:c++], [tag:html] and [tag:javascript]. Those tags are full of "I know more than you" tenuous close reasons. Cf, [Using typedef ClassName< > after class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764170/using-typedef-classname-after-class). That question is clearly not too broad.

Answer (score 26):

In my opinion the display should be changed completely.

Why not display all given close votes which receaved 2 or more votes (2 just as an example value) and display the voters only when hovering with your mouse over the specific reason.

This would have a few advantages:

- First of all you would be displayed at the close reason you deemed
  right (as asked by Xan or Patricia Shanahan).
- Secondly all used close reasons would be displayed. Why is that useful? Because the OP as well as ll future visitors will instantly see which errors were done in the question and not just the gravest problem.
- and last point by displaying the names only while hovering you keep the site a bit cleaner/better to read

Now to explain my 2nd point which is the most important in my opinion:

We all see questions we deem bad for various reasons lets say all the following reasons apply: Too broad, badly formatted, off topic, no own work,...

Now this question gets closed because of one of those reasons lets say: too broad. This OP as well as other visitors will think: "Ok this was just to broad, lets be more specific." What is the result?

- either the OP edits his question fixing this one issue (the others remain) and doesn't understand why his question is not reopened.
- he(or one of the other visitors) opens a new question which will be closed for one of the other reasons

Final result new bad questions and OP's who don't understand why their new question is closed. THey get frustrated and either leave the site (not what a Q&A site wants) or they keep asking bad questions because 3 out of 5 bad questions still get an answer.

We should try to educate them and its really disturbing to fix a given mistake just to get another mistake pointed out which were there before.

Comment: I agree with getting all >1 close reasons to display, but that doesn't happen all that often that all applicable close reasons get voted on. Maybe as an idea, keep close voting open even after the question has hit the 5-vote count, so that people who wish to spend a close vote (on an already closed question) to highlight a problem can do so. It needs careful consideration though. This can potentially be abused.

Answer (score 0):

I started to write a complaint ("question") here that is essentially the same as this one by @Xan.

This is what I'd like to say about this topic, with some suggestions of alternative text to use.

---

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32540122/729907).

The automatic SO text printed says, incorrectly and inappropriately:

> The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:...

I am listed as one of those voters, but I did **not** give that reason. I voted to close because the question is unclear.

IMO, the text should say something less definitive and misleading.  Here is one suggestion

> Some of the users who voted to close gave this reason:...

And here is another:

> Among the reasons given for voting to close was this:...

Another possibility is to wait until you get sufficient voters agreeing on the same reason, and then list their names.  What is not legitimate is to list users as having given a reason that they did not give.

Answer (score -32):

I think this would be too confusing to a user who has never seen a closed question before.  We need to focus on the *consensus* close reason, not the minority opinions.

Comment: You also need to not misrepresent people who voted to close. Not all of them may have voted to close for the same reason. If you're showing a concensus opinion, say so.

Comment: Note that if a gold badge user closes a question as a duplicate, the close reason goes with their vote, even if the other four used a different reason (even if they used the same different reason).  But all the users are shown as proposing it as a duplicate.

Comment: I guess a good in-between solution would be to only show the popular reason on the page, but then to have a detail link with the complete breakout.

Comment: I'd say it's confusing if you fail at reading comprehension. The text "the users [...] gave this specific reason" could simply be changed to something like "these reasons were given by the users who voted to close" followed by a list of all reasons given ("signed" by the specific users). Also, the current close reasons are inherently confusing for users who are not accustomed to SO and can't understand why their code dump is closed as "unclear" or their simple requirements dump as "too broad". And anyways, who says it's in SOs best interest to optimize towards not confusing these people?

Comment: If it's confusing - add inline help for new users.

Comment: What's confusing is telling lies about who voted for what.

Comment: Y'all are way overthinking this.  Don't forget that the closing system applies to all SE sites, not to just the programmer sites where pedantry runs amok.

Comment: Consensus? Closing isn't about consensus, it's about closing! There is no consensus. Things can be closed with 5 different reasons.

Comment: @bjb568: The OP doesn't need a blow-by-blow, nor do they need multiple explanations.  What they need is the reason and explanation that was chosen by the most close voters.  Who chose what is largely irrelevant to the OP.

Comment: We're talking about OP? Ok, don't show who voted at all! It doesn't help. For the rest of us (with 3k) maybe show signatures and all close reasons.

Comment: @bjb568: I can think of maybe a dozen things that the SE developers could be spending time on that are all more important than this.

Comment: "What they need is the reason and explanation that was chosen by the most close voters." Then don't show the other names. I'd rather see a small amount of information than a small amount of information plus some lies.

Comment: @boann: What lies?  In the OP's example, it shows clearly who voted for the majority opinion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you actually read OP's post, he explains that it only does the individual breakdown for "off-topic" reasons. Otherwise it falsely lumps everyone together under the majority reason, as in the second linked example.

Comment: @boann: Seems like that could easily be fixed by simply removing the phrase "The users who voted to close gave this specific reason"

Comment: @RobertHarvey [There is no such phrase displayed on offending pages.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5727357)

Comment: @Boann: Seriously, nobody needs to know this information at this level of detail.  Ask yourself: how would your workflow change if you knew precisely who used what kind of vote to close?  How would that change the way other community members perceive the close voters?  The effect is vanishingly close to zero.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm unhappy closing a question if I disagree with the majority reason, to the point of having avoided closing such questions. So my workflow would change in that way. Also, when I see an invalid close reason selected, I'm always curious to know who selected it.