# Should close-votes and duplicate-marks be combined?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions

I'm aware that when 5 users vote to close a question, and they choose different reasons, only the reason chosen by the majority is shown, and all users are listed as having chosen this reason. (I find this mildly annoying, but I understand the choice to keep things simple.)

I noticed that a question I voted to close as "too broad" was closed as a duplicate of another question, and I'm listed as one of the people who marked it as a duplicate. However, I see **close-voting** and **duplicate-marking** as **two very different things**; the former comments on the question's **quality**, the latter comments on the asker's **lack of effort** in finding the duplicate.

*(In this particular case, I thought the question was very broad and didn't show any effort by the asker, but I disagree with the choice of duplicate.)*

So my question is two-fold:

- Should close-votes and duplicate-marks be added up to decide whether to close a question (as they are now) or add up to 5 seperately?
- Should the users who voted to close and the users who marked as duplicate be listed together when a question is closed (as they are now) or listed seperately?

Comment: To answer your questions: No, and yes.  If a question is vague enough to garner close votes across the board, it makes sense to list them as the majority.  It shows there are multiple issues with the question; if it's actually a dupe, then editing it to bring that out would be a good idea.

Comment: Damn, I posted this just after the Documentation update; bad timing :-(

Comment: Side note: duplicate does not in any way talks about effort spent on researching question - just the fact it is already answered. Use downvotes indicate lack of research.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov By "lack of effort in finding the duplicate" I mean lack of effort in searching SO to find if the question has already been asked, which would have resulted in finding the duplicate.

Comment: The amount of time you spend searching doesn't necessarily correlate to your ability to find a duplicate. Granted, sometimes it is extremely obvious and merely searching the question's title would find the duplicate. But it isn't always that easy, and sometimes requires knowing the right terms to search for. For an expert, it is easy; for the person asking the question, it might not be. Thus, the attitude that duplicate == no research effort is a bad one, and leads to people being erroneously "offended" when their questions are marked as duplicates.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree that my claim that "duplicate = lack of search effort" is a bit simplistic, but my point is that a close vote and a duplicate mark point out different problems with the question, so I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to lump them together.

Comment: You describe the process quite well. What I don't see described here is what the actual problem is. In the end the question is closed, and serves as a duplicate marker pointing towards better content (I hope). Where is the problem?

Comment: @Gimby I wonder if it's logical that a question marked as a duplicate by three people can get closed as such because two more people think it's too broad. Those two votes in no way support the claim that the question is a duplicate. (Granted, they do mean five people think there are problems with the question. But "too broad" could be fixed by the asker improving the question.)

Comment: @m69 see it the other way, if it were illogical and the site should trigger on individual closure reason counts, it would take quite a bit longer for questions to actually get closed - if at all if only 5 people choose to vote and they have different ideas. But in the end all people voting are doing it towards the same target - to get the sucker closed down. So again - what is the problem with what the site does now, which is to throw them on the same pile?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181870/why-is-only-1-reason-displayed-on-closed-questions-when-different-reason-votes-w and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271000/extend-specific-close-reason-signatures-to-all-close-reasons

Comment: @Gimby I agree that we should probably be closing more questions, not fewer. Still, it was a bit strange seeing myself listed as having voted for something I disagreed with.

Comment: Understandable. But that is still not a problem, only a temporary state of being ;)

Answer (score 2):

My opinion: it is dishonest for the site to say:

> marked as duplicate by M.M, Shreevardhan, n.m., πάντα ῥεῖ

when in fact I did not mark as duplicate (I voted to close because it didn't contain a MCVE).   Imagine if someone did this at scientific peer review or something, combining all the rejection reasons into one and attributing the one reason to all the reviewers. People would take legal action to clear their name.

I'd rather the different votes be listed (the same way that different duplicate links are all listed); but in lieu of that, it should only list the name of those who actually voted for the reason being displayed.